# How do I correctly add my folder to the classpath in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

So I'm trying to simply add a folder of resources I must load in my application using getClass().getResource(...).

I've tried just about everything, but I can't seem to get it to work.

According to the layout below, what I want to do is to load a resource from the **scenes-fxml** folder from the **ViewManager** class, which logically I should be able to do with:

```
getClass().getResource("/scenes-fxml/MainScreen.fxml");
```

However, it does not work. I've tried adding the folder to the Eclipse class path in the run time (... which feels odd seeing as it should be captured within the context of the project folder, which is already there by default in eclipse).

I also tried changing the folder into a source folder, which didn't help. Is there something else I can do?

Here is my project layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmUY3.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All folders in your project that are not on the classpath (not source-folders in eclipse) can't be found by getResource().

**EDIT:**

So you have to copy "scenes-fxml" into the src-folder to use "/scenes-fxml/MainScreen.fxml".
 The leading slash in your path tells the resource loader to search from root of all classpath folders (here the src folder). As an alternative you can mark the "scenes-fxml" as source folder so that it's added to the classpath and use "/MainScreen.fxml" to find it.

You may also use a relative path to search for resources. Then you need a path relative to the class that calls getResource()...

Here's the java doc (IMO a bit complicated)
http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html

Comment: The leading slash doesn't mean what you think it means. A "project" doesn't exist anymore at runtime. A project is an eclipse concept, not a Java concept.

Comment: Well I think it's easier to explain the resource/folder/classpath stuff in the eclipse context if the question is related to it. The java runtime doesn't know about the eclipse project itself but eclipse maps the project source folder structure to the output-folder/jar/classpath as stated. Anyway, I corrected my answer...

Comment: Adding the resource folder to the class path ended up fixing it. I think I'd rather avoid adding non-source folders to the source folder, if I can help it :)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple actually. Let's say that `scenes-fxml` is marked as a source folder. Everything directly under this folder is thus in the root, default package. Just like if you had a .java file directly under `src`, the class defined in this .java file would be in the default package.

So, mark the `scenes-fxml` as a source folder, and use

```
getClass().getResource("/MainScreen.fxml");
```

If you want to use the path `/scenes-fxml/MainScreen.fxml`, then the MainScreen.fxml must be in the "package" `scenes-fxml`, and you thus need a folder named `scenes-fxml` **under** (and not *as*) one of your source folders. You shouldn't use a `-` character though, since it would make your package name invalid.